# Empty field deserialized to null instead of taking default value

Tags: java, csv, kotlin, jackson-databind

Following is my data class

```
@JsonPropertyOrder("firstName", "lastName", "age")
data class Data(
@JsonProperty("firstName") val firstName: String = "Default",
@JsonProperty("lastName") val lastName: String,
@JsonProperty("age") val age: Int
)
```

When I try to deserialize it with jackson, the object is containing the null values instead of the default.

```
val input = ",test,10"
val reader: ObjectReader = (CsvMapper().registerModule(KotlinModule()) as CsvMapper)
        .readerWithSchemaFor(Data::class.java)
val readValue = reader.readValue<Data>(input)
print(readValue.toString())`
```

Is there a way i can set the default value in case of null/empty string present in the csv input ?

Comment: I think there is an open issue on Jackson for this: https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-kotlin/issues/130

Comment: @Joffrey Thank you for sharing this issue. But the issue that you shared is for the json data. We fixed it by registering the kotlinmodule in the csvmapper. For me with json data it's working. But the same thing is not working when i am using csv data.